# jQuery ajax call not returning 'data' to redirected page on success call

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
<a href="PHP/LogOut.php" id="LogOut">Log Out</a>
```

the link a#LogOut calls a PHP script that ends all sessions and responds with data of "You have logged out".

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION = array();
    if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
        $params = session_get_cookie_params();
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}
session_destroy();
echo "You have logged out";
?>
```

Everything works fine except that once you are logged out and returned to the log in page the 'data/message' is not being written to the page. I am suspecting this is due to 'document.location.href'. If I place a 'console.log( data )' it flickers in the console for a split second, then disappears when the return page is loaded. How do I get this to run the script, redirect and display a message?

```
$('a#LogOut').live('click',function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $(this).attr('href'),
    success: function(data){
    var message = $(data).text();
    if (data==="You have logged out") {
    console.log( data );
    document.location.href='/returnedpage.php';
    $('#messageBox').show().html('<ul></li>' + data + '</li></ul>');

 } else {
    alert('not working');
 }
}
  });
  return false;
});
```

I could re-load the content with the .load function, but this has pissed me off and I want to get it right. Basically, I need the 'message' to be written to div#messageBox on the 'returnedpage.php' page. TY

Comment: You simply can't redirect and expect the data to still be there. Once a new pageload occurs, all data is lost, and the only way to keep it would be to store it in cookies, local storage, in a database or pass it as GET (querystring) or POST to the next page. Since you're getting the data with ajax, why not just store the data in the session serverside instead of returning it, and retrieve it on the next page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if I am not completely understanding your issue - but you console log prior to the redirect, so you see the *data* from the console.log. Then you are redirected and that *data* is gone on the subsequent page.

Where is #messageBox located, on the current page OR the redirected page?

1. If on the current page, you'd probably want to put the redirect after this:

   $('#messageBox').show().html('
  ' + data + '
  ');

And add some delay to it so the user can see the message prior to the redirect.

2 If you want to message on the redirected page, then my guess is you'd have to pass data at the end of the url as a param..

```
document.location.href='/returnedpage.php?thisData=' + data;
```

And then on the redirected page, grab the name/value pair for "thisData" and then display it.

Apologize if I am totally offbase to your issue.

To do number #2 - on the subsequent page you can just do something like:

```
*** caveat: this is JUST FOR THIS ONE USE CASE. I am assuming thisData is the ONLY param in the url.
```

and in this page, just do this.

```
<div id="messageBox" display="none"></div>

<script>
var url = document.URL;
var dispData=url.split('thisData=')[1];
$('#messageBox').show().html(dispData );
</script>
```

Comment: James - nailed it. Any tips on how to 'grab the name/value pari for 'thisData' and then display it'?

Comment: updated my original comment with a simple solution. Keep in mind that this solution is just for this one off. If you were gonna pass multiple name/value pairs then you'd need something more robust. This is Just assuming you have ?thisData=data etc... that is it, on the end of the href.

If its useful for you and you use it/accept it, please don't hesistate to give me a "checK" :-)

Comment: Actually it returns 'undefined'

Answer (score 2):

Based on @james emanon's reply I was able to get something that suited me a little better. He did answer the question I asked in a great manner so he gets his 'checK'. What I did do was remove the ajax call and change the last lines of the PHP to this:

```
header ("Location: /FXCM/FXCM-Conversion.php?status=LO");
exit();
```

I figured why make jQuery append the url with a parameter when I can just do it server side.
Then in the JS I did this:

```
    var url = document.URL.split('status=')[1];
    if(url == undefined) {
        url = '';
    }
    if(url != ''){
        var message = 'You are logged out';
        $('#messageBox').show().removeClass('error').html('<ul><li>' + message + '</li></ul>');
    }
```

After some thinking on it, I think this is the way to go. Much thanks to all of the above who helped me THINK and LEARN not just C&P - this time I appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it on the returnedpage, not on the current page.

Either pass in something via querystring (e.g. `?lo=1` signifying loggedout), use a specific logged out page where, by hitting it, you know you only got there by clicking logout (e.g. `loggedout.php`), or set a temporary cookie, read it on returnedpage.php, use it to show the message, and delete the cookie after its one-time usage.  Those are the three methods I've seen employed.

Comment: Great guys! thank you, I was afraid of that! I appreciate the guidance!